# selenium fails to open intended new window

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate web based application (asp.net) through selenium web driver.

Web application has login page and once I log in, I need to click on a button that opens a new window and then perform operations on this new window. So far, my code is able to login and click the button. Two problems here:

- instead of opening desired window on click, it opens the login page
- this login page is opened in the same window, not new one

I have used below statement to switch to new window:

```
webDriver.SwitchTo().Window("newwindowname");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the window handle?

Get the window handles

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
String myWindowHandle = handles.LastOrDefault();
```

And use the last one in the swtichTo statement

```
webDriver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle );
```